# MariaDB - GROUP BY with an order

Tags: sql, mariadb

So I have a dataset, where I would like to order it based on strings `ORDER BY FIELD(field_name, ...)` after the order I wan't it to group the dataset based on another column.

I have tried with a subquery, but it seems like it ignores by `ORDER BY` when it gets subqueried.

This is the query I would like to group with `GROUP BY setting_id`

```
SELECT *
FROM `setting_values`
WHERE ((`owned_by_type` = 'App\\Models\\Utecca\\User' AND `owned_by_id` = 1 OR ((`owned_by_type` = 'App\\Models\\Utecca\\Agreement' AND `owned_by_id` = 1006))) OR (`owned_by_type` = 'App\\Models\\Utecca\\Employee' AND `owned_by_id` = 1)) AND `setting_values`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
ORDER BY FIELD(owned_by_type, 'App\\Models\\Utecca\\Employee', 'App\\Models\\Utecca\\Agreement', 'App\\Models\\Utecca\\User')
```

The order by works just fine, but I cannot get it to group it based on my order, it always selects the one with lowest primary key (id).

Here is my attempt which did not work.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM `setting_values`
    WHERE ((`owned_by_type` = 'App\\Models\\Utecca\\User' AND `owned_by_id` = 1 OR ((`owned_by_type` = 'App\\Models\\Utecca\\Agreement' AND `owned_by_id` = 1006))) OR (`owned_by_type` = 'App\\Models\\Utecca\\Employee' AND `owned_by_id` = 1)) AND `setting_values`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
    ORDER BY FIELD(owned_by_type, 'App\\Models\\Utecca\\Employee', 'App\\Models\\Utecca\\Agreement', 'App\\Models\\Utecca\\User')
) AS t
GROUP BY setting_id;
```

Here is some sample data
[image]

What I am trying to accomplish with this sample data is 1 row with the id 3 as the row. 
The desired result set from the query should obey these rules

- 1 row for each `setting_id`
- `owned_by_type` together with `owned_by_id` is filtered the following way `agreement = 1006`, `user = 1`, `employee = 1`.
- When limiting the 1 row for each `setting_id`it should be done with the following priority in `owned_by_type` column `Employee, Agreement, User`

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/565110/5) with it.

Running MariaDB version 10.2.6-MariaDB

Comment: Why don't you show the actual query rather than approximations that will need to be corrected later?

Comment: You are misusing MySQL's notorious nonstandard extension to `GROUP BY`. `SELECT *` is generally unable to give predictable results in a `GROUP BY` statement. Read this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: @LoztInSpace Updated with the whole query and some data in a table.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Yeah, select * group by etc is a weird My SQL ism that really doesn't make any sense. Perhaps try to build a query with standard SQL. Also most database engines will throw away the order by in a sub query unless there's a top/limit clause as that construct also makes no sense. Sort your final output only. Try for more normal SQL. Good luck!

Comment: MariaDb also supports the window functions like [ROW_NUMBER](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/row_number/).  Which is sometimes used in other databases (MS SQL, Teradata, ...) to get the unique results based on an order.  So I wonder if the sql on the bottom of [this page](http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/how-to/get_top_n_each_group) would work in MariaDb.

Comment: Why GROUP BY if you have no aggregation?  Will DISTINCT work in MariaDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the Optimizer is free to ignore the inner ORDER BY.  So, please describe further what your intent is.

Getting past that, you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( SELECT
            ...
            GROUP BY ...
            ORDER BY ...  -- This is lost unless followed by :
            LIMIT 9999999999  -- something valid; or very high (for all)
         ) AS x
    GROUP BY ...
```

Perhaps you are doing [*groupwise max*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max) ??